# Record type of nested prop of type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I had the following type in one of my interfaces:

```
export interface CardProps {
  component?:
    |  'BatteryHealth'
    |  'DriveHealth'
    |  'SSDTrim'
    |  'ThermalDashboard'
    |  'MainFeature'
    |  'DiskSpace'
    |  'Benchmark'
    |  'Scanning'
    |  'Uninstaller'

  // other props of the interface
}
```

I was using that interface to create a type for another object related to this:

```
const components: Record<CardProps['component'], React.ComponentType> {
  // and here it gives me keys for that new components object
  // that match the possible values of the component property, like so:
  BatteryHealth: BatteryHealthComponent,
  DriveHealth: DriveHealthComponent,
  // ...
  // which is exactly what I want.
}
```

Now thigs have changed a bit and I had to rework that interface, and it now looks like this:

```
export interface CardProps {
  component?:
    | { type: 'BatteryHealth'; props: BatteryHealthCardProps }
    | { type: 'DriveHealth'; props: DriveHealthCardProps }
    | { type: 'SSDTrim'; props: SSDTrimCardProps }
    | { type: 'ThermalDashboard'; props: ThermalDashboardCardProps }
    | { type: 'MainFeature'; props: MainFeatureCardProps }
    | { type: 'DiskSpace'; props: DiskSpaceCardProps }
    | { type: 'Benchmark'; props: BenchmarkCardProps }
    | { type: 'Scanning'; props: ScanningCardProps }
    | { type: 'Uninstaller'; props: UninstallerCardProps }
}
```

Component is no longer a string, its an object with 2 properties `type` which is a string and `props` which is another interface corresponding that must be attached to that string value.

The problem is that now my Record type is no longer working, and that of course is normal, because component is no longer a string, its an object, so I have tried to do the following:

```
const components: Record<CardProps['component']['type'], React.ComponentType> {
  BatteryHealth: BatteryHealthComponent,
  DriveHealth: DriveHealthComponent,
  // ...
}
```

My keys are still there and errorless, but now the place where I use these components gives me an error:

```
Type '{ img: ImageContainerProps; icon: ImageContainerProps; } | 
      { img: ImageContainerProps; } | 
      { iconImg?: ImageContainerProps; description?: string; } | 
       ... 5 more ... | 
      { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type '{ img: ImageContainerProps; icon: ImageContainerProps; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

And when it was just a plain string name of the component, it was all working just fine and there were no errors.

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/1zb2yif

Answer (score 1):

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBMFMDMEsDtKgJ4HsCuAnUAHTqcBnUAQ2JNACsSA3MgY01hwBdTNMTlQBaCVeAHI20VJgDmkNgCIyoegMItpAKAXwlufEVABeUAG0VAb1AtkOSAC5QggEIkWLSJmQAJSCQA2LABaCAGi0CQhtBQlQAW0gePBDBUABfAJMzC2tbABEmGkgPbz9A4KIwiOjY7UIE5NTzSzCAZQbMgBUmSKK4ktsymK6qpJTTOozBFt8XSO9Msl8AI1QSTHBOytKovsrqobT62wBZEgQAMU8WLEhVkPXy-u3a9LDM2EIAawacEnpLoP6bzfigwee3skHg9F8U0wryu3XCGwqgJqw0etga9BI8HgCHEsNCPQRdyBKJBAFVsRoWN4vC48f9EUR7gBdUjEdRKFQqECgSAADxYnHobD8SH6rNIu0gKhGoAAwktwAAFSp6SWoaDFQgGeDoSJzFxMznstgKSI4ARglj4gBKkAUywAPPLlsqQgZhOlBEygkomPBxAA+VXGFSgUAOJwudyeHy+GzSUSoaQpMPZWC5fKx+NzJbJ0OgACS8DoXlg4FlUXNiHgLHjqF8oHgSdA3Jc+EwQTkfMsQsg4BUiSAA)

```js
// define your props as a javascript array - don't forget "as const"
const props = [
{ type: 'BatteryHealth', props: 'some-props' },
{ type: 'DriveHealth', props: 'some-props' },
{ type: 'SSDTrim', props: 'some-props' },
{ type: 'ThermalDashboard', props: 'some-props' },
{ type: 'MainFeature', props: 'some-props' },
{ type: 'DiskSpace', props: 'some-props' },
{ type: 'Benchmark', props: 'some-props' },
{ type: 'Scanning', props: 'some-props' },
{ type: 'Uninstaller', props: 'some-props' },
] as const

// extract the props as a type
type CardProps = typeof props[number]

const components: Record<CardProps['type'], string> = {
  BatteryHealth: "foo",
  DriveHealth: "bar",
  InvalidComponent: "oh no" // error, as expected
}
```